# How do the Pentax 18-55mm and 18-135mm compare in image quality?

Tags: lens, zoom, image-quality, sharpness, pentax

I've been reading a lot about the [Pentax DA 18-135mm lens](http://www.pentaximaging.com/product.aspx?id=smc%20PENTAX-DA%2018-135mm%20F3.5-5.6ED%20AL%20[IF]%20DC%20WR&cat=camera-lenses) and its performance compared to other lenses.  I've heard that this lens is [very soft at 135mm regardless of aperture](http://www.photozone.de/pentax/597-pentax_18135_3556?start=1).  However, I've also read that the [image quality is overall better than the 18-55mm lens](http://www.pentaxforums.com/reviews/pentax_18-135mm_review.php).  I am confused about the performance of the two lenses as a result.  Since I own an 18-55mm lens (came with my Pentax K-r), how does the image quality of the 18-135mm lens compare to the 18-55mm, especially wide open in the edges and corners?  Is it better or worse than the 18-55mm in terms of resolution?

Comment: The PhotoZone test of the 18-135 was abysmal. So bad that it seems like a bad sample, though Pentax said otherwise. http://www.photozone.de/pentax/597-pentax_18135_3556

Comment: I can't help but think that the PhotoZone test was based on a bad unit, but I can't say for sure until there are more resolution tests for this lens.  I'm still waiting for [LensTip](http://www.lenstip.com/) to test this lens.  I wanted to make sure that it was no worse than my 18-55mm kit lens.  That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty decent lens, despite what the Photozone review says. You've already seen the Pentax Forums review that includes crops of a chart. I'd trust your eyes over what some chart with numbers on the web says.

I've had the lens for a few months, and it's softer in the corners at the telephoto end compared to my DA* 50-135mm. Despite that, the 18-135mm lens is my most frequently used lens as it's "good enough" and it covers a very useful range.

Comment: After reading the [user reviews at Pentax Forums](http://www.pentaxforums.com/lensreviews/SMC-Pentax-DA-18-135mm-F3.5-5.6-ED-AL-IF-DC-WR.html), I've come to the conclusion that the PhotoZone test was based on a bad unit, since the user reviews indicate that the lens actually performs very well at the 135mm end.  Thanks!

Comment: I put very little stock in MTF charts these days simply because all lenses I've used have been "sharp enough", even the kit lenses that came with the K-5 (i.e. the 18-55 & 50-200). Put it this way, over the years there has _never_ been a photo where I thought "If only I had a sharper lens, this photo would be better" whereas I've frequently slapped myself for not bringing a lens that was wide/long/fast enough.

Comment: It depends where you start. Never tried the 18-135mm but when I had to send my DA* 16-50mm for repairs, my first idea was to get the 18-55mm as a cheap backup. Big mistake, the quality is horrible, everything looks like it was shot in a dark tunnel. I deleted all the photos from it, returned it and bought another 16-50m. After that I felt silly ruining good photos just to save $800. The lesson is to be careful with expensive gear, it is impossible to go back after!

Comment: It sounds like your 18-55mm lens was broken.

Comment: Not really broken but similar to what I see with other kit-lenses. I'd say the Pentax is a little sharper than average but vignettes more and stopping down has little effect on that near wide-angle. Maybe I could have sent it for warranty service saying it vignettes too much.